# Magento 2 : Two same products in cart but one must be FREE

Tags: magento2, product, cart, free-gift

I need to implement a functionality that do this :

After an api call, I get some SKU of product. This product needs to be added to the cart, but as a free product.

By doing this, this could cause a conflict issue with a possible existing product not free already in the cart

How to achieve this ?

1) Add a free product to cart

2) Avoid conflicts with existing product

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.